# JavaFX - MediaPlayer - How do I change the cursor while the media player is loading the image?

Tags: java, javafx, media-player

I am using OpenJDK 15.0.1 and JavaFX 15.0.1 on Windows 10.

I have provided a UI to allow a user to select a video from their machine using a FileChooser.  Once selected the video will start to play in a MediaPlayer.  Loading the video takes a little time depending on the size of the video.  During this time, I am trying to change the cursor to a WAIT cursor so the user knows the system is processing their request.

Nothing I have tried works.  I have deleted or commented out all lines that change the cursor back to DEFAULT in the entire code base.  I am setting the cursor to WAIT on every JavaFX Node I can find that has the method.  I have cut and paste the following lines in between every line of code in the button's action method that opens the FileChooser and loads the video into the MediaPlayer:

```
mediaView.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
videosTabGrid.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
primaryStage.getScene().setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
primaryStage.getScene().getRoot().setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
```

The whole time the video is loading, the cursor is the ARROW.  As soon the video loads, the cursor changes to WAIT.  I just can't find a way to change the cursor while the video loads.  Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This all had to do with the UI thread.  This was not the typical UI blocking thread issue since the MediaPlayer is itself a JavaFX UI component.  The solution was two fold:

1. Start a new thread inside of the UI thread to off load the work
   being done.
2. Inside the new thread, run the UI changes inside of a
   Platform.runLater() method.

Here is the example code:

```
primaryStage.getScene().getRoot().setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
new Thread(){
    public void run() {
        try {
            ...
            [MEDIA PLAYER VIDEO LOAD HERE]
            ...
        } finally {
            Platform.runLater(() -> primaryStage.getScene().getRoot().setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT));
        } // try finally
    } // run
}.start();
```